# Office add-in js extension change document name

Tags: javascript, ms-office, office-addins

I am trying to develop a simple office extension that will add suffix to document name on save event.
After spending a couple of hours, I didn`t found any way to catch save event and no way to change a document name.

One thing I have found is to get a document path (in case it is saved earlier) on local machine with:

```
   //Get the URL of the current file.
  Office.context.document.getFilePropertiesAsync(function (asyncResult) {
    var fileUrl = asyncResult.value.url;
    if (fileUrl == "") {
      app.showNotification("The file hasn't been saved yet. Save the file and try again");
    }
    else {
      app.showNotification(fileUrl);
    }
  });
```

Is it possible? If not, it will be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't yet have plans to add an API to change the name of the current file. Depending on the solution you're working on, one avenue to explore which might make sense is to manipulate the files you're interested in using the [Microsoft Graph REST APIs](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/overview/overview).

-Michael (Program Manager for Office add-ins)

Comment: Thank you for a quick answer. Unfortunately REST APIs can`t help us in our solution, because the documents are not in the cloud. In addition, we need this to work on the local machine with OS X operating system.